# How do I find multiple values on the same line in any permutation using Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I am using Notepad++, and I'm trying to find a way where I can search for multiple values on the same line. The regex search is not working for me currently, as I may not know which order the values are in.

For example, I want to search for a line of code which has three specific values. Using `.*` in the regex search is not working as you must know the order of the values. Is it possible for me to search for these lines without knowing the order of the values?

On each line I have perhaps a trading log which has 30 different tags.
I want to search for `35=D, EUR/USD, 150=8`. I only want to search for entries with all three values present.

The issue I run into is that the order of these tags are not guaranteed, so the regex search I use below does not always find each entry I require.

```
35=D.*EUR/USD.*150=8
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a FIX message parser?

Comment: Is this really just a regex question?  Seems like the answers would work in most editors with a regex search?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is much more efficient and can deal with any number of alternations without increasing complexity:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- *"Find what"*: `^(?=.*\b35=D\b)(?=.*\bEUR/USD\b)(?=.*\b150=8\b).+$`
- Check *"Match case"*
- Check *"Wrap around"*
- Check *"Regular expression"*
- ***Uncheck*** *"`.` matches newline"*
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # Beginning of line
  (?=           # Start positive lookaead, make sure we have after:
    .*          # 0 or more any character but newline
    \b          # Word boundary to be sure not matching 135=DATA
    35=D        # Literally
    \b          # word boundary
  )             # End lookahead
  (?=           # Start positive lookaead, make sure we have after:
    .*          # 0 or more any character but newline
    \b          # Word boundary
    EUR/USD     # Literally
    \b          # Word boundary
  )             # End lookahead
  (?=           # Start positive lookaead, make sure we have after:
    .*          # 0 or more any character but newline
    \b          # Word boundary
    150=8       # Literally
    \b          # Word boundary
  )             # End lookahead
  .+            # One or more any character but newline
$               # End of line
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Answer (score 10):

To match only those lines where all three strings exist, you can use the alternate `|` operator and group `(...)` your patterns to build a regex for all possible permutations:

```
(35=D.*EUR/USD.*150=8)|(35=D.*150=8.*EUR/USD)|(EUR/USD.*150=8.*35=D)|(EUR/USD.*35=D.*150=8)|(150=8.*35=D.*EUR/USD)|(150=8.*EUR/USD.*35=D)
```

A readable version with added linebreaks:

```
(35=D.*EUR/USD.*150=8)|
(35=D.*150=8.*EUR/USD)|
(EUR/USD.*150=8.*35=D)|
(EUR/USD.*35=D.*150=8)|
(150=8.*35=D.*EUR/USD)|
(150=8.*EUR/USD.*35=D)
```

This would match all lines where a combination of `35=D`, `EUR/USD` and `150=8` (and possible text inbetween) is present. In this sample text, only the last three lines would have a match (button "Find All in Current Document"):

```
some text 35=D
some text EUR/USD more text 150=8
some text 35=D more text EUR/USD more text 150=8
some text EUR/USD more text 35=D more text 150=8 more text
some text 150=8 more text EUR/USD 35=D more text
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hello, | is the or operator in notepad++? like || in php and javascript?

Comment: hi Freddy, the problem is i want all 3 tag values present in the same line. Using the "|" to separate the patterns doesn't work for me as it will highlight an entry if it is 1 value is present in 1 of the lines. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: Updated to match only lines with all three values.

Comment: @user726730 the | operator is a regular expression feature, nearly all RE libraries (including in PHP and JS) Support that. It is of course something different than boolean or biteise or in those programming languages

Comment: This is matching `USD/EUR 2150=85 35=D` or `USD/EUR 150=8 35=DATA`

Comment: @Toto Nobody said that the strings have to be separated by any kind of (word) boundary, so yes...